# Merge txt files in folder

Tags: file, text, command, line

I need to merge txt files into one txt file (they are in the same folder) in a command line. This works:
for %f in (*.txt) do type "%f" >> output.txt

However I need name of each file before the content like:
Name of file1
Content of file1
Name of file2
Content of file2
etc.

What is the code for the command line?

Comment: Do you write a Windows - cmd - file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
for %f in (*.txt) do echo %f >> output.txt & type %f >> output.txt
```

Note that *output.txt* will end up in the file as well, because once it's created it matches your `*.txt` file mask. You may want to redirect to `output.tmp` instead, and then after everything else is combined rename it.